# page name, or argumentless URL string in smarty?

Tags: smarty

I have a search form, and I want to create a "Start Over" link that just returns users to the page without any arguments. What Smarty code can I use? For example, if they are at `http://website.com/search.php?value1=x&value2=y`, I want to get `http://website.com/search.php` or just `search.php`, so I can construct `<a href='{$string}'>Start Over</a>`.

Answer (score 0):

I would just fill a variable in your php that you send to smarty? you could get that in smarty I guess, but that's not really a good way. just do something like this:

```
$yourSmartyVar->assign("string",$_SERVER[’PHP_SELF’])
```

That should give you the scriptname without querystring if I remember correctly. If it doesn't you could use $_SERVER[’SCRIPT_NAME’] if that suits you better, or even use http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php